# Is there elegant way to terminate running instance of spring boot stand alone application?

Tags: spring-boot

I've been playing with spring boot version 1.5.8 release lately. I was able to stand it up as rest web service to handle incoming request.

This is how I activate the service. Note: linux environment.

```
nohup java -jar fooservice.jar &
```

Then I tail the `nohup.out`file to monitor the start up process, any incoming request, any exception thrown and etc.

My question is how to terminate the instance of the program? I run `ps -ef | grep` command to find pid of the running instance then run `kill -9` command to terminate it.

Is there elegant way to stop the service?

Comment: I find the `jps` command is slightly more useful than `ps` as it narrows down to only Java processes and displays Main class for easy identification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shutdown spring boot application by enabling actuator shutdown end point  `/actuator/shutdown`, first we need to enable it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown)

```
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
```

And then invoke it

```
localhost:port/actuator/shutdown
```